# android app crashes because of lowmemory killer but profiler shows otherwise

Tags: android, android-studio

context: my phone has a 3GB RAM
my application crashes and based from logcat it says because of low memory killer,
however in the android studio profiler, it crashes even the memory of the app is bellow 1 GB used.

see logs here

```
2020-12-17 22:47:29.156 1329-11118/? I/ActivityManager:   MemInfo: 191628 kB slab, 676 kB shmem, 0 kB vm alloc, 32092 kB page tables 26688 kB kernel stack
               4412 kB buffers, 639856 kB cached, 245032 kB mapped, 1104300 kB free
      ZRAM: 244244 kB RAM, 1677720 kB swap total, 1038624 kB swap free
      Free RAM: 1503536 kB
      Used RAM: 1451262 kB
      Lost RAM: -96554 kB
      ExtraMemInfo: 
2020-12-17 22:47:29.157 11222-11235/? D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(175:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:175;Function:ASN1_get_object
2020-12-17 22:47:29.164 1329-11118/? W/DropBoxManagerService: Dropping: system_server_lmk_uevent (10 > 0 bytes)
2020-12-17 22:47:29.168 1329-11118/? D/DropBoxManagerService: file :: /data/system/dropbox/system_server_lmk_uevent@1608216449164.lost
2020-12-17 22:47:29.170 1329-11118/? D/AES: onEndOfErrorDumpThread: system_server_lmk_uevent Process: lowmmeorykiller
    Subject: Low on memory maybe memleak 

2020-12-17 22:47:29.194 11258-11258/? D/AEE_AED:   Backtrace:Process: lowmmeorykiller
    Subject: Low on memory maybe memleak 
    Build: OPPO/CPH1729/CPH1729:7.1.1/N6F26Q/1572535473:user/release-keys
    
    Low on memory:
      ntv   N   157125: logd (pid 314) native
      ntv   N   135528: faced (   78,692K memtrack) (pid 658) native
      ntv   N    50728: cameraserver (      756K memtrack) (pid 593) native
      ntv   N    34746: surfaceflinger (   18,944K memtrack) (pid 394) native
      ntv   N    25226: audioserver (pid 592) native
      ntv   N    13636: vtservice (pid 572) native
      ntv   N     8074: media.codec (pid 573) native
      ntv   N     7662: volte_imcb (pid 23013) native
      ntv   N     7509: zygote (pid 589) native
      ntv   N     5592: transport (pid 8010) native
      ntv   N     4852: mtk_agpsd (pid 582) native
      ntv   N     4650: mediaserver (pid 599) native
      ntv   N     4312: mtkfusionrild (pid 23111) native
      ntv   N     4230: mnld (pid 581) native
      ntv   N     3996: media.extractor (pid 598) native
      ntv   N     3754: mediadrmserver (pid 597) native
      ntv   N     3280: zygote
2020-12-17 22:47:29.194 11258-11258/? I/AEE_AED: Process: lowmmeorykiller
    Subject: Low on memory maybe memleak 
    Build: OPPO/CPH1729/CPH1729:7.1.1/N6F26Q/1572535473:user/release-keys
    
    Low on memory:
      ntv   N   157125: logd (pid 314) native
      ntv   N   135528: faced (   78,692K memtrack) (pid 658) native
      ntv   N    50728: cameraserver (      756K memtrack) (pid 593) native
      ntv   N    34746: surfaceflinger (   18,944K memtrack) (pid 394) native
      ntv   N    25226: audioserver (pid 592) native
      ntv   N    13636: vtservice (pid 572) native
      ntv   N     8074: media.codec (pid 573) native
      ntv   N     7662: volte_imcb (pid 23013) native
      ntv   N     7509: zygote (pid 589) native
      ntv   N     5592: transport (pid 8010) native
      ntv   N     4852: mtk_agpsd (pid 582) native
      ntv   N     4650: mediaserver (pid 599) native
      ntv   N     4312: mtkfusionrild (pid 23111) native
      ntv   N     4230: mnld (pid 581) native
      ntv   N     3996: media.extractor (pid 598) native
      ntv   N     3754: mediadrmserver (pid 597) native
      ntv   N     3280: zygote64 (pid 588) native
      ntv   N     3187: netd (pid 600) native
      ntv   N     3051: drmserver (pid 594) native
      ntv   N     3000: volte_stack (pid 23007) native
      ntv   N     2478: lldb-server (pid 9303) native
      ntv   N     2399: aal (pid 571) native
      ntv   N     2153: wpa_supplicant (pid 10540) native
      ntv   N     2009: atci_service (pid 532) native
      ntv   N     2000: criticallog (pid 565) native
      ntv   N     1964: /init (pid 1) native
      ntv   N     1674: vold (pid 319) native
      ntv   N     1627: ged_srv (pid 2496) native
      ntv   N     1524: pq (pid 570) native
      ntv   N     1494: adbd (pid 7706) native
      ntv   N     1330: bspCriticalLog (pid 587) native
      ntv   N     1208: mcDriverDaemon (pid 313) native
      ntv   N     1204: ueventd (pid 265) native
      ntv   N     1164: em_svr (pid 401) native
      ntv   N     1127: wfca (pid 395) native
      ntv   N     1096: emdlogger1 (pid 23077) native
      ntv   N     1054: rutilsdaemon (pid 1639) native
      ntv   N     1028: volte_ua (pid 23012) native
      ntv   N      990: keystore (pid 59
2020-12-17 22:47:29.194 11258-11258/? I/AEE_AED: $** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** Fatal *** *** *** *** *** *** *** **$
```

Android profiler says we have enough memory to worked on at the time of the crash, the sudden drop at the end means the app already crashed.
[image]

The thing is, thats not even the highest peak the app got, a few screens ago the app reached 1GB RAM usage total but no crash, they got freed succesfuly. See bellow

[image]

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: You should add `android:largeHeap="true"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks I will try it, I was just wondering why profiler says it is still way bellow 1GB and crashes with low memory while it exceed 1GB before and did not crash, somewhat profiler from android studio is not reliable at this point